# c# how to bind data to different class with same Object

Tags: c#

Here I have 2 classes as

Employee class as

```
public class Employee{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Department class as

```
 public class Department{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    }
```

Dal Project

```
public classs ModelDal{
public string cally(Employee objemployee){---}
}
```

Bal Project

```
public class BalModel {
ModelDal oModel =new Model();
public string caller(Department odept){
oModel .cally(odept);

///Here im getting error as enter employee class 
}
}
```

any one help me how can i over come this issue. i dont want to create any class with the name Employe

Comment: sorry mate but it is yet unclear for me what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is. Please explain this: `ModelDal oModel =new Model();` where is the `Model` class ? How is the department related to the employee class? I guess this: `oModel .cally(odept);` gives you a compilation error telling that it expects an `Employee` object as input.

Comment: @MongZhu Yes here i dont want to create Employee class is it possible from Department cls

Comment: "is it possible from Department cls" I don't know, because I don't understand the relationship between the 2 classes. I only see that they have the same properties.